# PHP SQL Database How to program a Search with Filter

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, filter

below is my searchData.php , which does the searching of the database.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Search Results</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
   font-size: 15px;
   color: #343d44;
   font-family: "segoe-ui", "open-sans", tahoma, arial;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-image: url("invoker.jpg");
  }
  table {
   margin: auto;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
   font-size: 12px;
   width: 100%;
   color: gold;
   font-weight: bold;
  }

  h1 {
   margin: 25px auto 0;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 17px;
  }

  table td {
   transition: all .5s;
  }
  
  
  .data-table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   font-size: 14px;
   min-width: 537px;
  }

  .data-table th, 
  .data-table td {
   border: 1px solid #e1edff;
   padding: 7px 17px;
  }
  .data-table caption {
   margin: 7px;
  }

  
  .data-table thead th {
   background-color: #508abb;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  
  .data-table tbody td {
   color: #353535;
  }
  .data-table tbody td:first-child,
  .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
  .data-table tbody td:last-child {
   text-align: right;
  }

  .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
   background-color: #f4fbff;
  }
  .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
   background-color: #ffffa2;
   border-color: #ffff0f;
  }

  
  .data-table tfoot th {
   background-color: #e5f5ff;
   text-align: right;
  }
  .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
   text-align: left;
  }
  .data-table tbody td:empty
  {
   background-color: #ffcccc;
  }
 </style> 
</head>
<body>


 <h1><u>Search Reviews</u></h1>
 
 
 <table class="data-table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>FaceBook User</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Review</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 
 <?php
  
  session_start();
  $friends = $_SESSION["friends"];

  define ("DB_USER", "yeospace_nm0102"); 
  define ("DB_PASSWORD", "ap3545"); 
  define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); 
  define ("DB_NAME", "yeospace_nm0102"); 

  
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
  
  
  $author=$_POST["author"];
  $title=$_POST["title"];
  $date=$_POST["date"];
  $age=$_POST["age"];
  $review=$_POST["review"];
  

     









  
  echo "<table>";
  foreach ($friends as $friend){
   
        $sql="SELECT author, title, date, age, review FROM AddEntry WHERE fbUserID='$friend[id]'";
      
  
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
  
  
  if ($result){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    
  
    echo "<td>".$friend[name]."</td><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".$row[4]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
   }; 
  }
  }
  echo "</table>";;
  mysqli_close($dbc) ;
 ?>
 </tbody>
  
 </table>
 <button onClick="location.href='index.php'">Return to Home</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the searchEntry.php , basically the search form.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Search Reviews</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"/> 
</head>
<body>
 
 
      <form action="searchData.php" method="post">
      
        <h1>Search Review</h1>
        
        <fieldset>
          <legend><span class="number">1</span>Search Review Info</legend>
          <label for="author">Author:</label>
          <input type="author" id="author" name="author">
          
          <label for="title">Title:</label>
          <input type="title" id="title" name="title">
          
          <label for="date">Date:</label>
          <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
          
          <label>Age:</label>
          <input type="radio" id="under_13" value="under_13" name="age"><label for="under_13" class="light">Under 13</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="over_13" value="over_13" name="age"><label for="over_13" class="light">13 or older</label>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset>
          <legend><span class="number">2</span>Search Reviews</legend>
          <label for="review">Review:</label>
          <textarea id="review" name="review"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        
        <button type="search"> Search Reviews </button>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, my search is almost as good as my ListEntry.php which list everything from the database. I need to make it such that when people use my searchEntry.php users can search for a particular author or title that is stored in the database. Basically a filter search. Can anyone advise on how I should go about doing it? Thanks !

Comment: Only post code/markup that's relevant to the question. For example, your CSS is not relevant.

Comment: Just add more `WHERE`-clauses for the fields you want to filter. Also, you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating the variables in your query like that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How should I go about adding the WHERE clauses? What's the syntax like ? is it in the $sql statement?

Comment: You already have a `WHERE`-statement in your current query. Just add `AND colname = :paramname AND colname2 = :paramname2` etc. to add more conditions. To see how Prepared Statements work, I linked to the manual in my second comment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the advise on using AND in the WHERE clauses. I used AND and LIKE % statements to get it working . Now its working thanks. Please help me mark this question as answered thanks.

Comment: I added it as an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add more conditions to your current `WHERE`-statement.

To add more condintions, use the `AND`-operator, like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4  FROM table WHERE col1 = 'x' AND col2 = 'y' AND col3 = 'z'
```

You can have multiple `AND`-operators and you can check any column.

Read more about [logic operators in  MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html).

To make your queries safe, you should update them to use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating the values like you're currently doing. You can read more about [Prepared Statements in PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).